# SQL server how to insert / update / select multiple parent > node categories in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Ok here my table

[image]

`cl_CategoryId` int primary key auto increment

Ok now what i want to achieve is rather complex

Assume that i have the following product categories

`Home` > `Computer Hardware`

1: Check `Home` category exists or not. If not exists insert it into DB with `cl_ParentCategoryId` = 0

2: Checks `Computer Hardware` exists or not.

2.1: If exists but it has `cl_ParentCategoryId` = 0 update its `cl_ParentCategoryId` value = `Home` inserted or selected `cl_CategoryId` value and returns `cl_CategoryId` of existing `Computer Hardware`

2.2: If not exists insert it into db with `cl_ParentCategoryId` = `Home` inserted or selected `cl_CategoryId` value and returns new `cl_CategoryId` assigned to `Computer Hardware`

So result would be something like

```
1 : Home : 0
2 : Computer Hardware : 1
```

**Can i achieve this with a SQL server 2014 Query ?**

And can we make it somewhat recursive for more categories ?

Example `Home` > `Computer Hardware` > `Graphic Cards` > `Desktop Graphic Cards`

Thank you very much for answers

SQL server 2014

Comment: sure why not? you can create a stored procedure with your logic.

Comment: @Vland i prefer not using stored procedures if possible.

Comment: @Vland also i am very inexperienced with stored procedures exploding my head atm how to code it :D

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - What are you trying to achieve finally ? How is tthe db supposed to know that Computer Hardware should come under home and not some other category ?

Comment: you should first create your query in sql management studio, add your if/else logic, insert, update statements, step by step. once you've got a **working** query you can choose how to use it. a stored procedure or calling the sql code from your application.

Comment: @Vland that is why i am asking i failed to create such a working query on sql server. if i can manage it i can programmatically code it in c# easily. ty

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev i will supply proper query from C#. i only need a working SQL query.

Comment: sure, C# code will be useful

Comment: @Vland yes but i need a working sql query first :)

Comment: I misread: I thought you had already some C# code ready to be "translated" to SQL. instead you're asking us to do all your work. good luck

Comment: @Vland i have written everything here. Sure i can code it all inside c# however that wouldn't be as fast as executing on SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written up an example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/843094/1)

It assumes you have a list of related pairs in the c# side.

It uses a table type to represent the list of pairs on the SQL side. It then creates a stored procedure to update the Categories based on the pairs you pass in. This mechanism is called a [Table Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
-- defines a parent relationship
create type parentRel as Table (
  category nvarchar(200) not null,
  parent_category nvarchar(200)
);

go
Create Proc UpdateCategories @rels as parentRel readonly as

-- 1. Insert new items, generating ids
insert into Category (cl_categoryName, cl_ParentCategoryId)
select
    category,
    0
from
    @rels r
where
    not exists (
      select 'x'
      from Category c
      where r.category = c.cl_CategoryName
    );

-- 2. Update parent structure
update
  c
set
  c.cl_ParentCategoryId = isnull(c2.cl_CategoryId, 0)
from
  Category c
    inner join
  @rels r
    on c.cl_CategoryName = r.category
    left join
  Category c2
    on r.parent_category = c2.cl_CategoryName;
Go
```

Note, you'll either want to add a transaction to the stored procedure, or call it from within a transaction. Also, this mechanism assumes the category names are unique.

Comment: ty very much for answers so at your logic it first insert category names then updates parent category ids. i see. actually i decided to make combination of parentid & category name as a unique not only category name. however ty for answer.

Comment: Laurence i asked another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484665/trying-to-compose-a-stored-procedure-at-sql-server-with-programmer-logic-but-not ty very much if you answer that too